# How to prevent overlapping of images that are positioned randomly using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a gallery, it positioned randomly in **.container** on each page load.

My problem is images are overlapping when I load the page sometimes. Also images not inside **.container**

The JS is pretty simple:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.picture').each(function(i) {
        $pT=$(this).height();
        $pL=$(this).width();
        $(this).css({
            top:Math.floor(Math.random()*$pT)*i*2,
            left:Math.floor(Math.random()*$pL)*i*2
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AHReF/

I've looked the web for a jquery solution to prevent overlapping images, but I couldn't find one that fits my specificities. If you just take a look at my problem and share a bit of your science, I'd be very grateful. Thanks!

Comment: i needs to be coded hard, try to find a jquery plugin for that

Comment: Can you give me an example

Comment: When placing the images, you could possible use [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect) to reposition something if it is overlapping with an other element.

Comment: Thank, does not seem to solve my problem

Comment: What if there is not enough space to place the images such that they would not overlap?

Comment: This plugin may help you reach a solution: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jquerycollision/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was asked before here: [Overlapping elements - HTML, CSS, and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302824/overlapping-elements-html-css-and-jquery)

I've adapted the code for your case in your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AHReF/1/

Define containerW and containerH (width and height of your gallery) to avoid getting pictures outside of where you want them to be.

We have to save each pictures dimensions and coordinates in `positions` and when trying to get random coordinates (top left values), we compare with the existing ones to see if it's overlapping or not.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help me! But images are overlapping when I use `$(document).ready` http://jsfiddle.net/AHReF/2/

Comment: You should do it on window load. It's overlapping on ready because it's not getting the right image sizes (images are not fully loaded yet)